# Why does mod_rewrite process the rules after the [L] flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There are the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) dir/index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule dir/index\.php.* - [F]
```

Why the last rule is processed and it returns Forbidden for all requests?

I need that if file or directory is not found then the next rule shouldn't be processed.

The next example isn't working for me as well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule dir/index\.php.* - [F]
RewriteRule (.+) dir/index.php?$1
```

It still returns Forbidden for all requests.

Comment: I think I have an answer. But what is the last line supposed to do?

Comment: [L] only works for the current itteration. The rewritten url, goes thought the same rewrite process, resulting in the forbidden-rewrite. Apache keeps on applying rules until the url no longer changes.

Comment: @Salman A, the last string supposes to restrict the direct access to UFL handler.

Comment: Direct access means requesting the file through a link like: http://domain.com/dir/index.php

Comment: @Gerben, oh I see.. but how to stop processing rules or to restrict direct access to url handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the last rule is processed and it returns Forbidden for all requests?

When the URL `foobar` is requested:

- The two conditions (line 2, 3) match

```cs
2   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
3   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

- Pattern matches, the resulting URL becomes `dir/index.php?foobar` with (line 4)

```cs
4   RewriteRule (.+) dir/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Note that the `[L]` flag causes the rewriting to stop; but **it does not stop Apache from having another go at the *rewritten* URL** since it has changed (see below about handling .htaccess directives).

With `dir/index.php` as the input URL:

- The condition does not match (line 2) since file exists
- Jumps to line 5

```cs
5   RewriteRule dir/index\.php.* - [F]
```

- Pattern matches, hence the Forbidden error

When directory or filename changes, Apache has to re-evaluate various configuration sections (e.g. `Directory` and `Files`) and the `.htaccess` file for the "re-written" path. This is why Apache might perform another iteration even when the previous one was ended with the `[L]` flag.

> The last string supposes to restrict the direct access to UFL handler.
> Direct access means requesting the file through a link like: domain.com/dir/index.php

I think adding another condition before line 5 should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} dir/index\.php\x20HTTP/\d\.\d$
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

The `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the request sent by the browser without any rewriting applied. This could be useful to detect what page was *originally* requested by the browser.

> THE_REQUEST
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g.,
> "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional
> headers sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped
> (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

Comment: Last string could be shorter: RewriteRule . - [F]

Comment: and also add [NC] flag cause someone can write diR/index.php and get the access to the file :)

Comment: Yes it helped me but I don't have yet enough reputation to vote for it. Is there way to printout or to see somehow the content of mod_rewrite variables like THE_REQUEST or REQUEST_FILENAME?

Comment: What does he mean it causes it to stop but it doesn't stop it from having another go. What does that mean.On the other go where does it begin to process from.

Comment: When mod_rewrite has completed processing a URL (e.g. by reaching the end of .htaccess or encountering `L` flag) it hands over the rewritten URL to Apache. If the URL has changed, Apache has to process the **rewritten URL** again which may result in processing the same `.htaccess` file again.

Comment: Example: input URL was `/foo` and rules inside `/.htaccess` rewrite it to `/dir/index.php?q=foo`. Since filename has changed, Apache has to process all directives that apply to the new URL, for example, if the client is allowed to access `/dir/` and `/dir/index.php`. In the process, it will also fire all `.htaccess` that apply to `/dir/index.php` which includes `/.htaccess` and `/dir/.htaccess` (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure of what you meant by "the next rule".

But if you don't want some rules to be executed when a non-existent file is requested, then using the following structure may help. (The following piece of code is copied from the [Apache RewriteRule Flags Page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s))

```
# Is the request for a non-existent file?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If so, skip these two RewriteRules
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]

    RewriteRule (.*\.gif) images.php?$1
    RewriteRule (.*\.html) docs.php?$1
```

And also using [R] for redirecting instead of [L] might help with the problem of returning Forbidden for all requests.

Comment: it's written there: The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. But they are!